# Trying to make a live USB

Tags: 14.04, boot, live-usb

So I have been trying to make and get working a Live USB for Ubuntu (14.10) on a Windows 8 machine with UEFI. I have downloaded the iso, run pendrivelinux's Universal USB installer, and then when I go to restart I end up back in windows. The boot order is USB first, I disabled quick boot, and now I am stuck. I can't figure out what is going wrong at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It says [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) that you also need to disable Intel Smart Response Technology. Read the wiki and make sure that all the requirements are met.

Also at boot try to chose on what media you want to boot on. (You have a boot menu where you can select it, I usually do it by pressing F12 on my computer but it may be different on yours). Even if it doesn't work at least you might get some error messages that way.

Answer (score 0):

Dual Boot in Windows 8 Requires "Advanced Startup"

Option 1:
From CLI

```
Shutdown /r /o
```

Option 2

```
Shift + "restart"
```

Option 3

```
""Charms bar\Settings\Change PC Settings\Update and Recovery\Recovery\Advanced Startup\/" Boot alternate device or OS"
```

There are a few other ways to get there...
Or disable Windows Boot Manager and use Master Boot Record. This is a long story, but Windows version of UEFI requires the system boot into Win 8 in dual boot systems. After Win 8 boots  the OS is selected, even if it is a multi Windows system.
It sounds strange, but this way the boot order can be configured while the OS is live; that is without entering the legacy "boot menu".
Or, there are third party Linux based Windows Boot Managers, but it requires a fairly complicated manual installation.

Comment: Yes, likely you can find "legacy boot options" in the "BIOS" or whatever it is called now.

Answer (score 0):

are you choosing the option install inside windows when running the Ubuntu installer? if so is that what is prompting you to restart and then reopens windows?

that's what happened to me when installing my Ubuntu as my second OS, and it sounds like you have the same issue. if not sorry for the misunderstanding!

but my way to fix this was to choose the option "something else" when installing and make a separate hard drive partition for the OS and continue the install that way. and it worked fine. then when i rebooted my PC i got the choice to either run Ubuntu or windows in my bios.

let me know if this is the same issue you have!